# How do I split a linefeed delimited string in awk and use its output on the same command line in bash?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a two part problem using **awk** in **bash**, first to properly split linefeed delimited text, and second to use the output of awk in the same command line.

For the sake of an example, I would like to list the contents of the second subdirectory within a specific subdirectory.

Assume my directory structure is something like this:

```
$HOME/meals/dinner
           /dinner/appetizer
           /dinner/dish
```

I used the command below which returned text delimited by and ending in 0x0A

```
$ ls meals/dinner | awk '{split($0,a,"\\\\n"); print a[1]; }'
appetizer
dish
```

xxd output shows (00000000: 6170 7065 7469 7a65 720a 6469 7368 0a    appetizer.dish.)

As a test, I tried this, and it worked.

```
$ echo "AAA\nBBB" | awk '{split($0,a,"\\\\n"); print a[1]}'
AAA
$ echo "AAA\nBBB" | awk '{split($0,a,"\\\\n"); print a[2]}'
BBB
```

What is my split doing incorrectly with the output of ls?

**Second problem**: Even if I extract the delimited directory name, I am not sure how to use it as part of a subsequently executed command on the same command line.

As a simple test, I request an example to ls the extracted directory by name.

Thank you.

**Update:** I have a workaround, though not exemplary. Here # is the index of a specific subdirectory within an ordered list of subdirectories.

`find directory/. -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' | head -n # | tail -n 1`

However, @EdMorton has pointed out that *nix filenames allow linefeeds. For my purposes, the filenames are generated by a tool and won't have linefeeds but I would be thrilled to have a better solution.

Also, it became clear that my use of echo generated a false positive, and that my assumption that awk was treating \n as an escape sequence was faulty.

A few commentors have asked what I am trying to do. Apologies that my original post was not clear.

I want to get a single-depth list of subdirectory names within a known directory, I want to get the name of the Nth subdirectory based on my script needs, and I want to use that subdirectory name (ideally) in the same command line to process the contents of that subdirectory.

- the name of the main directory is the same as its project
- there is a known subdirector, say "assets", containing an unknown number of subdirectories, each named uniquely based on a number unique to the system, like a GUID but not.
- within each uniquely named subdirectory of "assets" exists uniquely named and ordered based, but the subdirectory names (for reasons known only to the tool creator) are unknown - just that they are ordered partly by type, partly by a unique number.
- the Nth subdirectory in any main directory will always contain a certain file type
- Example: `project/assets/70137592/402938/*` <e.g. all the files of a type>
  I have been assured the schema and numeric sort order of subdirectories within '70137592' will never change. :shrug:

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: `echo "AAA\nBBB"` isn't printing a newline, it's printing a literal backslash followed by the letter "n", and that's what your `awk` command is splitting on. If you want the second (newline-delimited) record, use `ls | awk 'NR==2'`. But parsing the output of `ls` is [generally a bad idea](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Would something like storing the list in an array, like `subdirs=(meals/dinner/*)` and then using `"${subdirs[2]}"` work? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: What does `echo "AAA\nBBB"` output for you (the answer will depend on the version of `echo` you are running)?

Comment: @Shawn For purposes beyond the example, in bash, I want a list of unknown (but consecutively identified) subfolder names and need to be able to get the Nth one without previously knowing its name. My goal was to **ls** the folder names and split them using awk, then index the Nth one based on the script (later processing any files therein.)  Based on the answer and comments, I can see my lack of knowledge in *nix is my enemy.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you for the information. In a rookie move, I forgot to use '''echo -e''' which would have avoided the false positive in my test. Your suggestion may work and is something I have not tried - still learning here. Again, thanks for the comment.

Comment: @EdMorton It turns out, the wrong thing. I should have been using '''echo -e "AAA\nBBB'' ''' when I was testing. I made a bad assumption about how **awk** was parsing \n and a mistake in not using '''echo -e''' - thanks for the assist!

Comment: @Hordeling Using `echo` with options (like `-e`) and/or backslashes is another thing that -- like parsing `ls` -- seems like a good idea, but tends to cause problems. [Different versions of `echo` treat options and backslashes differently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo), so what'll happen is unpredictable. (I once had a bunch of scripts break because an OS update had bash compiled with different options that changed how `echo` worked!) Use `printf`; it's more complicated to understand (its first argument is a format string), but more predictable.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Got it, thanks. I'm well-acquainted with printf and it sounds like that would be the way to go - though I didn't know bash supported that variation. Still a lot for me to learn on the Linux side. In any case, using `echo` was just me creating a test case to determine why *awk* didn't seem to be parsing the list, when it actually was parsing the literal characters `\n`. My real script doesn't use echo. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are splitting by a literal backslash, followed by the letter `n`. BTW, your `echo` command does not output a newline, as you can verify easily by

```
echo "AAA\nBBB"  | wc -l
```

which outputs `1` (i.e. one line).

You could do something like a

```
ls meals/dinner | head -n 1
```

to extract the first line.

Comment: Aw, man...that makes more sense. I made a terrible assumption that both echo and awk were treating the \n as an escape character.

1. I should have used echo -e "AAA\nBBB" for my test
2. I will try what you have described. 
3. I hang my head in shame as a Linux noob.
THANK YOU!

Comment: Based on feeback all around, I am using the equivalent of these commands for my bigger script, and it is returning the correct subfolder.

`find foldername/. -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' | sed -n '2 p'`

Comment: @Hordeling you know that file names can contain newlines, right? If you post a question about what you're actually trying to do then we can help you.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the info; I did not know Linux allowed linefeeds in filenames and will be wary of that. As for my post, I am not sure how to make it more clear. I want to get a list of subfolders within a folder, I want the Nth one based on my script needs, and I want to use that filename (ideally) in the same command line to process the subfolder contents. That said, once I have the Nth filename I would still have to create a variable and then use it in subsequent script command to do the work.

Comment: Nit-pick #1: what we're discussing is not specific to Linux, its about Unix, Linux is just one variant of Unix. File and directory (nit-pick #2: not "folder", "directory", folder is a Windows term) names in Unix can contain all characters except NUL and forward slash `/`. OK the answer you accepted does answer the question you asked because what you just said in your comment about `I want the Nth one` wasn't at all represented in your question and the right answer is not to pipe the output of find to sed - if you post a new question we can help you.

Comment: One improvement to remove sed would be to use both head and tail, as a variation to the accepted answer.

`find directory/. -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' | head -n # | tail -n 1` 

where # is the number of the subdirectory to be processed.  This does work in my real world script and doesn't invoke the heavier use of sed.

Comment: No, head and tail is not the answer either. I see you updated your question - [Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are highly discouraged as are asking multiple questions within one question. You should put this question back as it was when you accepted an answer to it as it was asked and ask a new question.

Comment: @EdMorton : While it is well known that filenames **can** contain plenty of nasty characters, which does include newlines, I wonder whether you ever have encountered in your life such a case....

Comment: @user1934428 absolutely I have.

Comment: seriously next `POSIX` standard should begin mandating no `\n` anywhere along any file/folder/device path. This must be one of the biggest mistakes ever, even more so than their utter failure in standardizing the syntax for `date` and `stat` between `bsd` and `gnu` variants.